# I don't understand this problem when I try to mount my NTFS data partition in Ubuntu 14.04, please help me mount it

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, windows-8, ntfs

I am a new user to Ubuntu Linux. My data which I saved using Windows in a separate data partition which is in the NTFS file system, is not mounting properly in Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty.
The error message which I'm receiving upon accessing my partition is:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/abdul/MYDATA: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda1" "/media/abdul/MYDATA"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

I do not understand this error message, so, please anyone guide me on this issue to mount my data partition successfully, and also give a permanent solution to this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Is windows on the same (NTFS) partition as your data?

Comment: try to fix with `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1` in terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T)

Comment: No, it is separate from my Windows partition.

Comment: Again, try to fix with `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1` in terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T)

Comment: Thanks @KasiyA it worked... just by entering "sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1" on the Linux terminal emulator.

Comment: But one thing more, @KasiyA, is there a permanent solution/fix to this issue in Ubuntu?

Comment: Boot into windows and run `powercfg -h off` in cmd(run as admin) to turn off hibernation feature and it will fix for next time in Ubuntu :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message, I think you didn't shutdown your Windows OS. Since your system is having dual boot OS, you need to shutdown it properly(i.e. neither hibernate nor sleep). Open your Windows OS and shutdown it properly, then again open your Ubuntu, your problem will be solved.!